# jQuery UI dialog remove outer glow and change text of close button

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

I'm trying to customize my jQuery UI confirm dialog window. Can't find how I can remove light blue outer glow from buttons (on hover), change close text button from "close" to "x" and remove close button hover background. 
Is there some documentation about all dialog classes somewhere?

This is the code:

```
function fnComfirm(title, content, btnId) {
    $("#dialog:ui-dialog").dialog("destroy");
    $("#dialog-confirm p").text(content);
    $("#dialog-confirm").dialog({
        title: title,
        resizable: false,
        height: 200,
        width: 486,
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
            "OK": function() {
                $( this ).dialog("close");
                if (btnId) document.getElementById(btnId).click();                  
                return true;        
            },
            Cancel: function() {
                $( this ).dialog("close");
                return false;
            }
        }
    });
    $('body').css('overflow','hidden');
    $("div[role=dialog] button:contains('Cancel')").css("background-image", "none").css("border", "0px solid #FFF");
    $('.ui-dialog :button').blur();     
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="dialog-confirm" title="Are you sure?"><p></p></div>
```

include:

```
<h:outputScript library="js" name="jquery-ui-1.8.min.js" />
```

Comment: the css on your visual elements with depend on the theme your using. please add a link of show some code

Comment: I don't need theme, I want to apply my styles. Partly did, just a few things need to be finished.

Answer (score 7):

For changing the close button text, you can pass in an option like title (in the dialog creation), called closeText.

```
$("#dialog-confirm").dialog({
    title: title,
    closeText : 'hello' //Changes the text of the titlebar-close button to hello instead of default Close
    ...
    ...
})
```

And to remove the outerglow(focus) from the close button, you can go into the css for the titlebar-close and mark outline property to be zero as follows:

```
.ui-dialog .ui-dialog-titlebar-close {
   outline: 0;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
Div.dialog({
    autoOpen: true,
    closeOnEscape: false,
    closeText: '',
    modal: true,
    draggable: false,
    resizable: false,
    width: 640,
    height: 420,
    close: function(event, ui) {
        if (orderModifyFlag == true) {
            messageDisplay(1000);
        } else {
            messageDisplay(651);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.